# Firebase App Distribution is not installing the app on Android 12

Tags: android, firebase, apk, android-12, firebase-app-distribution

We use Firebase App Distribution to deliver staging builds. Android devices below Android 12 can install it successfully, but on Android 12 it says "Installation failed".

**Important notes:**

1. No other versions of this app installed on this device
2. If we manually download debug or release APKs for this app they also install
3. We upload APKs to Firebase

Is there any Android 12 limitation I miss? Is there something new in Firebase what prevents us from installing APKs from it on Android 12?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem, if you target Android 11+ and distribute you have to use app signer to sign your APKs. In Bitrise CI you need to add `use_apk_signer: true` field to `sign_apk` step.

Comment: Hello. I believe I find myself in the same situation. I recently updated the target Android version to 12 and since then, the apps can't be installed on Android 11+. Looking at our distribution pipeline in Azure, we do have signing in place. There is a use of a keystore that is there for a longer time. Is it something that needs to be updated in order to work on the newer version? (maybe I am asking basic questions, but I am not a mobile developer, it's just that a few tasks regarding some mobile apps fell into my lap)